# How to remove the top bar from a resizable form on Windows 10?

Tags: forms, delphi, borderless

I am trying to remove title-bar of a form while keeping the border to have a resizable form. I set the `BorderStyle` to `bsNone` and override the `CreateParams` procedure:

```
procedure TMainForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or  WS_BORDER or WS_THICKFRAME;
end;
```

The only issue I am facing is a white bar on top edge of the form (in win 10):

[image: screenshot]

How can I get rid of this white bar?

Comment: I need WS_THICKFRAME to me the form resizable.

Comment: Setting the border style to `bsNone` makes the window not resizable.  Explore the `bsToolWindow` and `bsSizeToolWin` alternatives. Going down the WinAPI route can prove to be a lot of work.

Comment: And the form can be moved as well, right?

Comment: Yes, but moving the form is straight forward using WMNCHitTest. My problem is the white bar at top edge.

Comment: @Ron: bsToolWindow or bsSizeToolWin won't remove the tilebar.

Comment: Have you considered handling `WM_NCPAINT` and possibly `WM_NCACTIVATE` messages, painting the border the same color as your client area bg? I haven't tried with Win 10 (and can't do so right now)

Comment: It's been a while since you asked that but I created a repository with a solution without VCLStyles... Take a look on [my repository](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/DelphiProjects) and if you want I opened a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655376/create-a-borderless-form-without-losing-windows-commands/54673991#54673991) here too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going the win API way will consume a lot of time and can prove to be so hard. If you are willing to go that way I strongly recommend it. But for the current time here is a quick work around to your problem.

Use the [VCL Styles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/VCL_Styles_Overview) by changing the style of the title bar like this

go to `Tools-> Bitmap Style Manager` and reopen the Windows 10 style (since you want this in windows 10)

Go to `Objects-> form->title` and change the height to 5.

in your IDE's object inspector uncheck the border Icons and set the caption to `' '`.

The result will be a form with a title bar that is so thin, it is a border.

[image]

You can further modify the look of the title bar so it looks exactly like the borders.

and see this [`Vcl.Forms.TFormStyleHook.PaintNC`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Forms.TFormStyleHook.PaintNC) to know exactly how this is done using style Hooks.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi 11, and possibly earlier, you can create a resizable form without a title bar by using the form's **CustomTitleBar** property:

```
Enabled=true
Height=0
ShowCaption=false
ShowIcon=false
SystemButtons=false
SystemColors=false
SystemHeight=false

Form.BorderStyle=bsSizeable
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not handled by Delphi on Windows 10!
You must use a tweak tool to control the border size inside windows. 
I used winaero (www.winaero.com) and reduce the window border to 1
and padding to zero.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

for firemonkey (fmx) users: You can do this via styles.