# Create a borderless form without losing Windows commands

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rad-studio

I've changed my form to a borderless form, I just changed the `BorderStyle` property to `bsNone`, but now my application loses the windows anchor and some commands like

> WIN + ↑ (Align the form Client)
>    WIN + ↓ (Minimize the form)
>      WIN + →(Align the form Right)
>    WIN + ←(Align the form Left)

I've tried to set `BorderStyle: bsSizeable` and use the below code inside of the `FormCreate`, but this does not worked:

```
procedure TfrmBase.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetWindowLong(Handle
               ,GWL_STYLE
               ,GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE)
                AND (NOT WS_CAPTION)
                AND (NOT WS_THICKFRAME)
               );


  Refresh;
  FormColor := oLauncher.oCor;
end;
```

This results:

[image: My form]

The image above is what I want, but the Windows commands that I already have mentioned don't work

Have any way to set the `BorderStyle: bsNone` and don't lose these commands?

**EDITED**

If I use the `WS_THICKFRAME` my form returns a little top border and the windows commands works well, but I don't want that top border.

[image: My form2]

**EDITED 2**

I got very close to the expected result, but have a little problem yet...

I put this on my `FormCreate`

```
SetWindowLong(Handle
             ,GWL_STYLE
             ,GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE)
              AND (NOT WS_CAPTION)
              );
```

And I create the method

```
private
   procedure WmNCCalcSize(var Msg: TWMNCCalcSize); message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
```

and then

```
procedure TfrmBase.WmNCCalcSize(var Msg: TWMNCCalcSize);
begin
  inherited;
  if Msg.CalcValidRects then
  begin
    InflateRect(Msg.CalcSize_Params.rgrc[0], 0, 6);
    Msg.Result := 0;
  end;
end;
```

> I got this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393516/how-to-change-the-clientrect-of-a-form?rq=1)

Now the border has disappeared, but when my Form loses the focus, the top / bottom border is shown again....

***How can I avoid this?***

[image]

---

**SOLVED**

I left the border as `BorderStyle: bsSizeable`, then I did it:

```
private
  procedure WmNCCalcSize(var Msg: TWMNCCalcSize); message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
[...]
procedure TfrmBase.WmNCCalcSize(var Msg: TWMNCCalcSize);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  if not Msg.CalcValidRects then
    R := PRect(Msg.CalcSize_Params)^;
  inherited;
  if Msg.CalcValidRects then
    Msg.CalcSize_Params.rgrc0 := Msg.CalcSize_Params.rgrc1
  else
    PRect(Msg.CalcSize_Params)^ := R;

  Msg.Result := 0;
end;

procedure TfrmBase.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  SetWindowLong(Handle
               ,GWL_STYLE
               ,WS_CLIPCHILDREN or WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
               );
end;

procedure TfrmBase.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Width := (Width - 1);
end;
```

> **Solution at GitHUB**
>
> I've create a [repository here](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/DelphiProjects)

Comment: so basically you want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31199437/800214)?

Comment: @whosrdaddy Yes, I've already done this in C# with WPF, but I don't know how to apply this logic in Delphi... I did that in C#  and I didn't lose the windows commands.

Comment: basically you do the same thing (override createparams and override wndproc)...

Comment: For a system command to work, you need to have the corresponding system command enabled. I mean, you need WS_SIZEBOX, for instance for win->, to enable SC_SIZE. But that comes with the thick frame. IOW, the frame is what makes it work.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I tried this but a little border appears, look my question again, please.

Comment: That was my point.

Comment: Hey @SertacAkyuz I found your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8394131/10145630) that helped me a little. Do you know how I can avoid the **EDITED 2** problem?

Comment: You might be on the right track. You should perhaps paint the border yourself.

Comment: I don't get the deal though. Eventually you have a sizeable window, why don't you want to have it proper?

Comment: I want build my own title bar without losing the windows commands and without using styles... But if I use a BorderStyle: bsNone, my form loses these commands, then I'm using a BorderStyle: bsSizeable and i'm working to hide the title and his top border.

Comment: RE (solved): "* left the border as BorderStyle: bsSizeable*" - Note the "BorderStyle := bsNone;" in the OnCreate event handler, if you leave it out this doesn't work, the design setting doesn't take effect. Anyhow, I presume "Width - 1" is forcing a frame update, you can probably achieve it with SetWindowPos (SWP_FRAMECHANGED) or RedrawWindow (RDW_FRAME).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz If I leave `BorderStyle: = bsNone;` when I use WIN + Arrows the window looks strange, some parts of the screen get black

Comment: Ok, thanks. Seems to display different behavior on different environment, I don't like it. Try to test on as many OS as you can before deploying.

Comment: It's an internal software that help my team day-by-day, till now I have tested on Windows 10 and Windows 7, and with this change that I've done, works well on both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the commands you refer to are system commands related to sizing of the window. That requires the thick frame, without it "WIN + right" and "WIN + left" won't work. Additionally you need the minimize box and the maximize box for the WIN + up/down commands to work.

Best is to start from scratch and include the styles you need, otherwise VCL might interfere. If there's a possibility of your form to be recreated, put styling in a `CreateWnd` override.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, WS_CLIPCHILDREN or WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
end;
```

Then there's the frame that you don't want. In an edit in the question you inflate the client rectangle to get rid of it. Don't guess the frame width/height, do it like the below.

```
procedure TForm1.WMNCCalcSize(var Message: TWMNCCalcSize);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  if not Message.CalcValidRects then
    R := PRect(Message.CalcSize_Params)^;
  inherited;
  if Message.CalcValidRects then
    Message.CalcSize_Params.rgrc0 := Message.CalcSize_Params.rgrc1
  else
    PRect(Message.CalcSize_Params)^ := R;
  Message.Result := 0;
end;
```

Reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize) for the message is mandatory at this point, the parameters have different meanings at different stages, etc..

The above leaves a window without any non-client area at all. The client rectangle is equal to the window rectangle. Although the caption is not visible, you can activate the system menu by pressing Alt+Space. The problem is, the system insists on drawing activation state. Now it draws a frame in the client area!!

Get rid of it by intercepting `WM_NCACTIVATE`, you also need it to draw your title according to the activation status:

```
procedure TForm1.WMNCActivate(var Message: TWMNCActivate);
begin
  if Message.Active then
    // draw active caption
  else
    // draw incactive caption

  // don't call inherited
end;
```

You might have to deal with some glitches, messing up with the window has consequences. In my test, the minimized form does not have an associated icon in the alt+tab dialog for instance.

---

Below is my test unit in full.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure WMNCActivate(var Message: TWMNCActivate); message WM_NCACTIVATE;
    procedure WMNCCalcSize(var Message: TWMNCCalcSize); message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, WS_CLIPCHILDREN or WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
end;

procedure TForm1.WMNCActivate(var Message: TWMNCActivate);
begin
  if Message.Active then
    // draw active caption
  else
    // draw incactive caption

  // don't call inherited
end;

procedure TForm1.WMNCCalcSize(var Message: TWMNCCalcSize);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  if not Message.CalcValidRects then
    R := PRect(Message.CalcSize_Params)^;
  inherited;
  if Message.CalcValidRects then
    Message.CalcSize_Params.rgrc0 := Message.CalcSize_Params.rgrc1
  else
    PRect(Message.CalcSize_Params)^ := R;
  Message.Result := 0;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This worked *-*, you helped me a lot man!! Now I just need to make some adjustments...